# Laravel WhereNotNull always data missing

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I want to ask why when I call the pagination API the "**data missing**" error message always appears when using `whereNotNull.`

this is the code that I made.

```php
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $req = $this->request;

        $query = DB::table('voucher')->whereNotNull('voucher.type')
         ->where('type', '!=', '')->select('id', 'type', 'actived_at', 'expired_at', 'created_at');

        if ($this->request->has('sort')) {
            $sorts = explode(',', $this->request->sort);
            foreach ($sorts as $sort) {
                list($sortCol, $sortDir) = explode('|', $sort);
                $query = $query->orderBy($sortCol, $sortDir);
            }
        } else {
            $query = $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
        }

        $perPage = $this->request->has('per_page') ? (int) $this->request->per_page : 10;
        $pagination = $query->paginate($perPage);
        $pagination->appends([
            'sort' => $this->request->sort,
            'end_to' => $this->request->end_to,
            'per_page' => $this->request->per_page
        ]);
        return response()->json(new MP($pagination));
    }
```

in Resource Collection

```php
/**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'hashedId' => Hashids::connection('alternative')->encode($this->id),
            'created_at' => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'hour' => $this->getHour($this->actived_at),
            'price_type' => $this->type,
            'duration' => $this->getDuration($this->actived_at, $this->expired_at),
            'actived_at' => $this->actived_at
        ];
    }

    public function getHour($value)
    {
        return Carbon::parse($value)->format('H');
    }

    public function getDuration($start, $end)
    {
        $to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start);
        $from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end);
        $duration = $to->diffInMinutes($from);

        return $duration;
    }
```

Here I am trying to call the table name again but still "**data missing**"

Can anyone explain why?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this help you:

```
$query->get()
```

Comment: why should you use get ()

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Is this because of Carbon Format? I have added the resource collection to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, all of this is wrong from the code that I made. This "data missing" is because the data that I have haven't totaled ten.

like in this section code.

```php
$perPage = $this->request->has('per_page') ? (int) $this->request->per_page : 10;
```

if there is a per_page request the value will be returned according to the request, but if not this will be the default request of 10 data